# Merge two list based on Id

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have two lists based on the same model.

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public decimal? Val1 { get; set; }
    public decimal? Val2 { get; set; }
}
```

Here are my lists:

and the new merged list should contain only one row with `MyModel() {Id = 1, Val1 = 1, Val2 = 2}`

```
    var list1 = new List<MyModel>()
    {
        new MyModel() {Id = 1, Val1 = 1}
    };

    var list2 = new List<MyModel>()
    {
        new MyModel() {Id = 1, Val2 = 2}
    };

    var list3 = list1.Union(list2);
```

How can I do this using c#? I tried Union but it creates two rows.

Comment: Is the number of value fix? Or is it a bit more dinamyc?

Comment: looks like you want to join to columns based on Id, and get the not null column.But I don't think this is going to be usefull in any real life scenario.

        var list4 = from l1 in list1
                    join l2 in list2 on l1.Id equals l2.Id
                    select new MyModel { Id = l1.Id, Val1 = l1.Val1 ?? l2.Val1, Val2 = l1.Val2 ?? l2.Val2 };

Comment: or linq: `var list4 = list1.Join(list2, 
                l1 => l1.Id,
                l2 => l2.Id, 
                (l1, l2) => new MyModel
                {
                    Id = l1.Id,
                    Val1 = l1.Val1,
                    Val2 = l2.Val2
                });`